# Rewarded Ads NOT LOADING

Tags: android, admob

**Hello,**

I'm trying to display a rewarded ad, but it fails to load. I followed AdMob's official tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmrTF0hLsIk&t). This is the error:

```
E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.

I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
```

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reward);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    loadAd();
}

public void loadAd(){

    this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
    RewardedAdLoadCallback callback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(i);

            Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardedAdFailedToLoad");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
            super.onRewardedAdLoaded();

            Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardedTagLoaded");
        }
    };
    this.rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), callback);
}



public void showAd(){

    if (this.rewardedAd.isLoaded()){

        RewardedAdCallback callback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {

                Log.i(TAG, "OnUserEarnedReward");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                super.onRewardedAdOpened();

                Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardAdOpened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                super.onRewardedAdClosed();

                Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardAdClosed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int i) {
                super.onRewardedAdFailedToShow(i);

                Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardedAdFailedToShow");
            }
        };
        this.rewardedAd.show(this, callback);

    } else {

        Log.i(TAG, "Ad not loaded.");
    }
}
```

***All AdMob IDs used are just for a test, I got them in AdMob docs***

In manifest, I've added:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me, I only need to fix this to finish my app. I've been stuck in this error for two weeks, I'm very tired and I'm thinking about giving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The error was in the emulator! To load ads, we need wi-fi connection. AVDs with API =< 25 cannot connect to wi-fi. So I just installed Android Oreo and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever added test device id? It is easy to find test device id by filtering `AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice` in Logcat.

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but Logcat doesn't show my device id